# I am trying to print some predefined sequence in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, bioinformatics

I am trying to add to more paragraph but getting error? I am able to print first three paragraph but while I trying to add to more paragraph getting error. Can anyone please correct?

Input file:

```
HETATM10910  C4B NAD A 363      60.856 -58.575 149.282  1.00 40.44           C  
HETATM10911  O4B NAD A 363      61.320 -59.488 148.275  1.00 43.48           O  
HETATM10912  C3B NAD A 363      60.243 -57.426 148.473  1.00 40.37           C  
HETATM10914  C2B NAD A 363      60.167 -57.970 147.054  1.00 40.90           C  
HETATM10916  C1B NAD A 363      61.394 -58.766 147.056  1.00 43.29           C  
HETATM10954  C4B NAD B 363      41.496 -54.407 140.932  1.00 39.26           C  
HETATM10955  O4B NAD B 363      41.936 -54.715 139.568  1.00 41.96           O  
HETATM10956  C3B NAD B 363      42.061 -55.476 141.894  1.00 37.13           C  
HETATM10958  C2B NAD B 363      42.883 -56.336 140.942  1.00 38.13           C  
HETATM10960  C1B NAD B 363      42.233 -56.127 139.593  1.00 42.92           C
```

I want to print data as per following:

```
HETATM 3788  C4B NAI A 302      52.695  15.486   8.535  1.00 57.28           C  
HETATM 3789  O4B NAI A 302      52.258  14.631   7.456  1.00 56.26           O  
HETATM 3794  C1B NAI A 302      53.348  13.816   7.022  1.00 53.44           C 
HETATM 3792  C2B NAI A 302      54.537  14.748   7.190  1.00 50.93           C  

HETATM 3789  O4B NAI A 302      52.258  14.631   7.456  1.00 56.26           O  
HETATM 3794  C1B NAI A 302      53.348  13.816   7.022  1.00 53.44           C 
HETATM 3792  C2B NAI A 302      54.537  14.748   7.190  1.00 50.93           C 
HETATM 3790  C3B NAI A 302      54.225  15.525   8.465  1.00 52.99           C  

HETATM 3794  C1B NAI A 302      53.348  13.816   7.022  1.00 53.44           C 
HETATM 3792  C2B NAI A 302      54.537  14.748   7.190  1.00 50.93           C 
HETATM 3790  C3B NAI A 302      54.225  15.525   8.465  1.00 52.99           C  
HETATM 3788  C4B NAI A 302      52.695  15.486   8.535  1.00 57.28           C  

HETATM 3792  C2B NAI A 302      54.537  14.748   7.190  1.00 50.93           C 
HETATM 3790  C3B NAI A 302      54.225  15.525   8.465  1.00 52.99           C  
HETATM 3788  C4B NAI A 302      52.695  15.486   8.535  1.00 57.28           C  
HETATM 3789  O4B NAI A 302      52.258  14.631   7.456  1.00 56.26           O  

HETATM 3790  C3B NAI A 302      54.225  15.525   8.465  1.00 52.99           C  
HETATM 3788  C4B NAI A 302      52.695  15.486   8.535  1.00 57.28           C  
HETATM 3789  O4B NAI A 302      52.258  14.631   7.456  1.00 56.26           O  
HETATM 3794  C1B NAI A 302      53.348  13.816   7.022  1.00 53.44           C
```

same lie that for each chain. Chain ID may be A to H.
Code:

```
import os
import sys

d = {}
chainIDs = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D',)
atomIDs = ('C4B', 'O4B', 'C1B', 'C2B', 'C3B', 'C4B')
with open('1A7K.pdb') as pdbfile:
    for line in map(str.rstrip, pdbfile):
        if line[:6] != "HETATM":
            continue
        chainID = line[21:22]
        atomID = line[13:16].strip()
        if chainID not in chainIDs:
            continue
        if atomID not in atomIDs:
            continue
        try:
            d[chainID][atomID] = line
        except KeyError:
            d[chainID] = {atomID: line}

n = 4
for chain, atoms in d.items():
for atom, line in atoms.items():
    for i in range(len(atom)-n+1):
        for j in range(n):
            print d[chain][atomIDs[i+j]]
        print
```

Msg is:

```
runfile('C:/Users/Desktop/test_python_2.py', wdir='C:/Users/Desktop')
```

Comment: The error says: "`i` is an integer value. You cannot use `len` on it." Consider using `for j in range(i-n+1):`

Comment: @cel, used script is running but not getting result? msg is: runfile('C:/Users/Desktop/test_python_2.py', wdir='C:/Users/Desktop')

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
for i in range(len(atomIDs)-n+1):
    for j in range(len(i)-n+1):
        for k in range(len((j))-n+1):
            for l in range(n):
```

you take the length of `i` and `j`. These are integers (obtained from range), and as the error you receive states, `int` objects do not have a length as such (at least as far as Python's `len` function is concerned).

What precisely are you trying to do with these for loops? If you wish to print each line for each chain and atom, would something like the following would work?

```
for chain, atoms in d.items():
    for atom, line in atoms.items():
        print line
```

Comment: @kdmurray, I have edited my code but not getting expected result?

Comment: Can you please suggest me how to add input and output directory? I want to take input file from input folder and output will save to output folder with same name of input file.